# Order inside TreeMap wrong

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish-3

I try to store the "modules" data in a specific order inside a map. I use TreeMap to realise this. 
When I read the data i get it in exactly the wrong order. It starts with key value 9 and stops a 0. ??? Does JPA do s.t. else then "putting" the values into the TreeMap?

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy="prditem", 
    fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
    cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval=true,
    targetEntity=PubModule.class
)
@JoinColumn(name="prditmID")
@MapKey(name="order")
private Map<Integer, PubModule> modules = new PubModulesMap();
```

---

```
public class PubModulesMap extends TreeMap<Integer,PubModule> {

    @Override
public PubModule put(Integer key, PubModule value) {
    PubModule old = (PubModule)this.get(key);
        if (old!=null) {
            old.setPrditem(value.getPrditem());
    ....
}
```

---

```
Iterator <PubModule> it = list.values().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    PubModule pm = it.next();
    System.out.println(pm.getOrder());
}
```

9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

Comment: The map is sorted according to the natural order of its keys, not the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for unexpected order is that, JPA does not understand that the map should be sorted.

Generic solution would be to create a getter method for your map:

```
public Map<Integer, PubModule> getModules() {
   if (modules == null) {
      modules = new PubModulesMap();
   } else if (!(modules instanceof TreeMap)) {
      modules = new TreeMap(modules); // Or new PubModulesMap(modules)
   }
   return modules;
}
```

If you're using hibernate, you should add @Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL) annotation.

Comment: Perhaps you ought to state that your solution is totally Hibernate-specific, and that the user hasn't mentioned what JPA implementation is being used so may not work for him/her

Comment: I must admit, that I'm not using JPA all that often to remember that the solution was vendor specific.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that i'm using glassfish-3 (eclipselink 2.x). I would like to avoid a "order by" on the sql database. Do you think can do the sorting after loading the data from the sql server?

Comment: As the answer states, you can use custom get/set methods to convert the Map EclipseLink uses to your own sorted Map

Answer (score 1):

JPA uses its own Map implementation when reading from the database to support LAZY and change tracking.

For an EAGER relationship, you can use your own specific class if you wish.  Just set your field type to this class, or use a DescriptorCustomizer to configure the ContainerPolicy on the OneToManyMapping.

You can also define a transient field for the sorted map, and use your own get/set methods to lazy initialize from the persistence one.

You could also use an OrderBy to sort on the database.

Comment: I try not to make too much i/o on the database. That's why i did not do any orderby's there.